# Scala: generics and implicit

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

I have to develop class StackMachine[T]. If T = Boolean, then there should be logical operations. If T = Int,Double,Long and etc. there should be ariphmetic operations. Firstly i developed class Stack[T].

```
class Stack[T](val stack: List[T]) {
    val length: Int = stack.length
    def isEmpty: Boolean = {length == 0}
    def push(x: T): Stack[T] = {
      new Stack[T](x :: stack)
    }

     def peak: T = {
       if (this.isEmpty)
         throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
         else stack.head
     }
    def pop(): Stack[T] = {
      if (this.isEmpty)
        throw new ArrayStoreException()
      val x :: xs = stack
      new Stack[T](xs)
    }
```

The thin is that i dont know how to develop StackMachine[T] the presence of operations in which depends on the type.
I tried this:

```
case class StackMachine[T](val stack:Stack[T]){
    def const(x: T): StackMachine[T] = {new StackMachine[T](new Stack[T](this.stack.push(x).stack))}
    def dup: StackMachine[T] = {new StackMachine[T](new Stack[T](this.stack.push(this.stack.peak).stack))}
    def swap: StackMachine[T] = {
      val startStack = this.stack
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      val secondPeak = secondStack.peak
      val finalStack = secondStack.pop().push(startPeak)
      StackMachine[T](stack)
    }
    def and(): StackMachine[Boolean] = {
      val startStack = this.stack.asInstanceOf[Stack[Boolean]]
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      val secondPeak = secondStack.peak
      StackMachine[Boolean](new Stack[Boolean](secondStack.push(startPeak && secondPeak).stack))

    }

    def or: StackMachine[Boolean] = {
      val startStack = this.stack.asInstanceOf[Stack[Boolean]]
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      val secondPeak = secondStack.pop().peak
      StackMachine[Boolean](new Stack[Boolean](secondStack.push(startPeak || secondPeak).stack))
    }

    def xor: StackMachine[Boolean] = {
      val startStack = this.stack.asInstanceOf[Stack[Boolean]]
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      val secondPeak = secondStack.pop().peak
      StackMachine[Boolean](new Stack[Boolean](secondStack.push(startPeak ^ secondPeak).stack))
    }

    def sum(input : T)(implicit N: Numeric[T])  = {
      val startStack = this.stack
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      StackMachine[T](new Stack[T](secondStack.push(N.plus(startPeak,input)).stack))
    }

    def dif(input : T)(implicit N: Numeric[T])  = {
      val startStack = this.stack
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      StackMachine[T](new Stack[T](secondStack.push(N.minus(startPeak,input)).stack))
    }

    def mul(input : T)(implicit N: Numeric[T])  = {
      val startStack = this.stack
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      StackMachine[T](new Stack[T](secondStack.push(N.toDouble(startPeak).*(N.toDouble(input)).asInstanceOf[T]).stack))
    }

    def div(input : T)(implicit N: Numeric[T])  = {
      val startStack = this.stack
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      StackMachine[T](new Stack[T](secondStack.push(N.toDouble(startPeak)./(N.toDouble(input)).asInstanceOf[T]).stack))
    }

    def min(input : T)(implicit N: Numeric[T])  = {
      val startStack = this.stack
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      StackMachine[T](new Stack[T](secondStack.push(N.min(startPeak,input)).stack))
    }
    def max(input : T)(implicit N: Numeric[T])  = {
      val startStack = this.stack
      val startPeak = startStack.peak
      val secondStack = startStack.pop()
      StackMachine[T](new Stack[T](secondStack.push(N.max(startPeak,input)).stack))
    }



  }
```

But this is wrong, because operations shouldnt have input parameters because all variables have to be taken from Stack. More than that, this way i cant create diff and mul functions.
I thoght to make StackMachine[T] abstract and use imlplicit object, but failed because in that case, my functions cant return StackMachine. May be i just dont understand implicit well enough or there is another way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `def and()(implicit ev: T <:< Boolean): StackMachine[Boolean]` and for numeric operations you may take a look to the [**Numeirc** typeclass](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) - Althought. being honest. I guess what I would do would be to rather have different classes for different machines.

Comment: I would do it too, but this is the task. To tell the truth i dont understand how this construction helps, because ev doesnt have boolean operations

Comment: `ev` implies that `T` is a **Boolean** as such, you should be able to use **T** as a **Boolean** in the body of that method. However, if that was the intended solution you should already know about that. - Can you share the literal statement of your task? _(maybe you can't due plagiarism)_. It may also help if we could know which topic / technique you are expected to use here _(if this is homework)_ or what is the meta-problem you are trying to solve _(if this is for work)_.

Comment: Ok, but then i have an type mistmatch because in ````StackMachine[Boolean](new Stack[Boolean](secondStack.push(startPeak && secondPeak).stack)) ```` secondStack.push requires T but Found Boolean.

Comment: The text of task: In the course of the laboratory work, it is necessary to develop a generalized class (class variants are given in the attached tables).
A special feature of the task is that the meaning of some operations on objects of the class being developed depends on the type that this class is parameterized with. Moreover, even the
presence of some operations may depend on a typical parameter. This functionality is
implemented using implicit objects and implicit method parameters.

Comment: The Stack Machine[T] class, which represents an immutable snapshot of the
state of a stack machine that operates with values of type T. If
T is a numeric type, arithmetic operations must be implemented in the stack machine
. Logical operations must be present in the Stack Machine[Boolean]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then yeah it seems the project is intended to be solved using a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html).

For example, see this small one for **Boolean**-like `and`:

```scala
sealed trait BehavesAsBoolean[T] {
  def and(t1: T, t2: T): T
}

object BehavesAsBoolean {
  implicit final val BooleanBehavesAsBoolean: BehavesAsBoolean[Boolean] =
    new BehavesAsBoolean[Boolean] {
      override def and(b1: Boolean, b2: Boolean): Boolean =
        b1 && b2
    }
}

final class StackMachine[T](stack: Stack[T]) {
  def and(implicit ev: BehavesAsBoolean[T]): Option[StackMachine[T]] =
    for {
      // I changed the implementation of pop to return an Option[(T, Stack[T])]
      (b1, s2) <- stack.pop
      (b2, s3) <- s2.pop
    } yield {
      new StackMachine(s3.push(ev.and(b1, b2)))
    }
}
```

Of course, you may still prefer to throw exceptions rather than using `Option`
Anyways, I hope this helps you to finish the code.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/RNRS0OasSmmfN3HaIZQ6wA/5)*.

Comment: Thank youd for your help